# select all columns from distinct combination of three column

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database, azure-data-factory

I have to insert record to another table based on the distinct combination of three column. Table A has 50 columns, in that i have to take distinct value of three column and insert all the column values to another table. how i can do that ? I tried doing below but got error .

```
select * from engagementmasterstaging 
where EngagementId 
in (select distinct EngagementId,ServiceLine,SubServiceLine 
from engagementmasterstaging)
```

Comment: What error did you get? Apart from that your query doesn't look like an insert statement. It looks like a select.

Comment: @Serg Nice edit. Only it would have helped if you had added some line breaks and indentation. Without that the first revision was more readable.

Comment: If more than one row have the same value for EngagementId, ServiceLine, SubServiceLine from which row will you get the value of the other columns?

Comment: Hi, if you want all columns related to the distinct the columns, you have to set a logic for choosing between the same rows. What will you choose if you have two rows with same values in EngagementId,ServiceLine,SubServiceLine ? Do you have a date column so that you can choose newest one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all columns, use window functions:

```
select . . .    -- list the columns here
from (select ems.*,
             row_number() over (partition by EngagementId, ServiceLine, SubServiceLine order by EngagementId) as seqnum
      from engagementmasterstaging ems
     ) ems
where seqnum = 1;
```

If you have a primary key in the staging table, you can use that and still use `select *`:

```
select ems.*
from engagementmasterstaging ems
where ems.pk = (select min(ems2.pk)
                from engagementmasterstaging ems2
                where ems2.EngagementId = ems.EngagementId and
                      ems2.ServiceLine = ems.ServiceLine and
                      ems2.SubServiceLine = ems.SubServiceLine
               );
```

Comment: can you please help me understand the query ? a short description will be helpful.

Comment: @KunalSinha . . . What do you not understand?  `row_number()` is quite well documented.

Comment: first query I understood, I was asking about the second query where you have mentioned to use pk.

Comment: @KunalSinha . . . A primary key uniquely identifies each row.

Comment: thanks @Gordon, can you assist me on this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67316873/update-the-foreign-key-column-by-checking-updates-in-other-table-primary-key-col