# Update the Foreign key column by checking updates in other table Primary Key Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure-sql-database

I have to update the E_ID and other columns of table User which is FK and being referenced to M_ID column of Master table which is PK based on the LastModifiedOn column in master table. I'm trying to do using below update query but it's picking the first value of M_ID from master table i.e 1 and update all the values of user table E_ID to 1. Thanks

```
 update User
    set E_Id = m.M_ID
    from master m
    where cast(m.LastModifiedOn as date) = cast(getdate() as date)
```

**Master Table:**
[image: Master Table]

**User Table:**
[image: User Table]

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: I found that your sql statement means take the value of the first row in the master table to update the E_ID column in the user table. So when the value of M_ID in the first row is 2,  it will update all the values of user table E_ID to 2. I'm confused about your `where condition`.  Can you talk about your update logic?